# How to create a separate tracking column based on dates?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df:

```
df:
            val
date
2012-01-01  4.2      
2012-01-02  3.7
2012-01-03  6.2
2012-01-04  1.2
2012-01-05  2.4
2012-01-06  2.3
```

What I want to create is a column that starts at 0 for a specified date and fills in the column accordingly (assume the date in this case is 2012-01-04):

```
df2:
            val  tracking
date
2012-01-01  4.2  -3
2012-01-02  3.7  -2
2012-01-03  6.2  -1
2012-01-04  1.2  0
2012-01-05  2.4  1
2012-01-06  2.3  2
```

I tried using np.arange() but was having trouble centering on the row I needed.  The date column is set up as an index (pandas df).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to do it in two parts:

```
df['tracking'] = pd.np.arange(len(df))

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
            val  tracking
date                     
2012-01-01  4.2         0
2012-01-02  3.7         1
2012-01-03  6.2         2
2012-01-04  1.2         3
2012-01-05  2.4         4
2012-01-06  2.3         5

df['tracking'] -= df.ix['2012-01-04']['tracking']

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
            val  tracking
date                     
2012-01-01  4.2        -3
2012-01-02  3.7        -2
2012-01-03  6.2        -1
2012-01-04  1.2         0
2012-01-05  2.4         1
2012-01-06  2.3         2
```

Comment: Andy,  Thanks for the help.  df is actually a series currently.  When I do df['tracking'] = pd.np.arange(len(df)) I get 'tracking not in this series!'

how should I handle this?  Thanks.

Comment: You could simply make it a DataFrame: `df = pd.DataFrame(df)` :) *Note: it's probably good practice to only call DataFrames df!*

Comment: As a matter of practice, should I convert Series to one column DF's when doing joins and merges?  Or is it really a case by case basis?

Comment: @user1911092 I'm not sure I understand the question, can't you only do joins with DataFrames? Perhaps that should be another question.