# Python: How to create an event time column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
index                value
2011-04-25 09:44:30  0.008272
2011-04-25 09:45:00  0.008272
2011-04-25 09:45:30  0.007638
2011-04-25 09:46:00  0.005099
2011-04-25 09:46:30  0.001915
...                       ...
2011-04-28 15:45:30 -0.075017
2011-04-28 15:46:00 -0.075017
```

which spans 4 days, with 30 second intervals between 9:30-15:00 for each day.

If for instance the date-timestamp `2011-04-25 09:46:30` is my main "event" in my time-series, how can I create optimally a column, say `event_time` where I have a 0 at this date-timestamp, negative numbers for date-timestamp less than `2011-04-25 09:46:30` and positive numbers for date-timestamp greather than `2011-04-25 09:46:30`? I want a column that looks like [-1000, -999, -998 .... 0, 1, 2, .... 2200] where 0 correspond to the index = `2011-04-25 09:46:30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of three simple steps to achieve the objective:

1. Sort in order of datetime (assuming not already sorted)
2. Apply a numeric rank column basis the datetime
3. Find the rank for desired datetime, and shift (i.e., subtract) the column by that much. (eg.`df[c] = df[c] - 500`)

Not providing any code since you don't mention what you have tried so far. Hope this helps.

Juts found out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692982/how-to-create-a-separate-tracking-column-based-on-dates?rq=1) already exists.